# Laravel 5.2 subdomain dynamical routes to controllers

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-5

Lets assume I have a site with cars: `cars.com` on Laravel 5.
I want to set up my `routes.php` so a user could type in a browser  `ford.cars.com/somethingOrnothing` and get to the controller responsible for Ford™ cars (`FordController`).
Of course I could use something like this code:

```
    Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function () {     
        Route::group(['domain' => 'ford.cars.com'], function(\Illuminate\Routing\Router $router) {
            return $router->resource('/', 'FordController');
        });
    });
```

But I am not happy about writing and maintaining routes for hundreds of car brands.
I would like to write something like this:

```
Route::group(['domain' => '{brand}.cars.com'], function(\Illuminate\Routing\Router $router) {
        return $router->get('/', function($brand) {
            return Route::resource('/', $brand.'Controller');
        });
    });
```

*So the question is:* **Is it possible to dynamically set routes for sub-domains and how to achieve this**?

upd:
the desirable outcome is to have subdomains that completely repeat controllers structure. Like `Route::controller()` did (but it is now deprecated)

Answer (score 1):

To emulate `Route::controller()` behaviour you could do this:

```
Route::group(['domain' => '{carbrand}.your.domain'], function () {
    foreach (['get', 'post'] as $request_method) {
        Route::$request_method(
            '{action}/{one?}/{two?}/{three?}/{four?}',
            function ($carbrand, $action, $one = null, $two = null, $three = null, $four = null) use ($request_method) {
                $controller_classname = '\\App\\Http\\Controllers\\' . Str::title($carbrand).'Controller';
                $action_name = $request_method . Str::title($action);

                if ( ! class_exists($controller_classname) || ! method_exists($controller_classname, $action_name)) {
                    abort(404);
                }

                return App::make($controller_classname)->{$action_name}($one, $two, $three, $four);
            }
        );
    }
});
```

This route group should go after all other routes, as it raises 404 Not found exception.

Answer (score 0):

Probably this is what you need:

> ### Sub-Domain Routing
>
> Route groups may also be used to route wildcard sub-domains.
> Sub-domains may be assigned route parameters just like route URIs,
> allowing you to capture a portion of the sub-domain for usage in your
> route or controller. The sub-domain may be specified using the domain
> key on the group attribute array:
>
> ```
> Route::group(['domain' => '{account}.myapp.com'], function () {
>     Route::get('user/{id}', function ($account, $id) {
>         //
>     });
> });
> ```

From:
[Laravel 5.2 Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/routing#route-group-sub-domain-routing)

upd.

If you want to call your controller method you can do it like this:

> ```
> Route::group(['domain' => '{account}.myapp.com'], function () {
>     Route::get('user/{id}', function ($account, $id) {
>         $controllerName = $account . 'Controller' //...or any other Controller Name resolving logic goes here
>         app('App\Http\Controllers\\' . $controllerName)->controllerMethod‌​($id);
>     });
> });
> ```

Comment: Probably it is not.  I have read the docs and tried a lot of stuff before posting the question. The example from the docs is clear, what to do with controller routes and how to pass the `{account}` parameter to them is **not clear**

Comment: @Zanshin13 I see. As a work-around you can always call controller method from inside the route-closure like this: app('App\Http\Controllers\YourController')->controllerMethod($account, $id);

Comment: the desirable outcome is to have subdomains that completely repeat controllers structure. Like `Route::controller()` did (but it is now deprecated). Your solution will not give me options to go to any controller method I have in url